# Iterate over a dynamic dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Summary**:

I want to iterate over a dictionary which is dynamic.

Here dynamic means we will be deleting one key,value pair after some condition. So, lenght of dictionary will be changed.
But I am getting error in python:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

**Example:**

Lets have a code here:

```
a = {'p':'q','q':'r','s':'t'}

for key,value in a.items():
    if key == 'q':
        <some code here>
       del a[key]
       <some code here>
```

It gives Runtime Error over changing size of dict.

Comment: Well don't do that then. Why are you deleting an item from the dict you are iterating over?

Comment: Deleting a key while using `for key in a.items()` will make your loop do some nonsense.   You could mark that `key` for deletion later.

Comment: dont delete during iteration. make a copy of the dict with the items that you want to keep instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items()` method returns a generator that will return a tuple `(key, value)` for every iteration step until it will raise and `StopIteration`. Please see [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

You can convert the generator to a list by doing `list(a.items())` and then it will work because now you have the entire list of keys and values and is no more linked to the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Do not delete `key` while iterating `dict`. Using dict comprehension to create a new dict and assign to your variable `a` if needed

```
{k:v for k,v in a.items() if k!='q'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not really using the value there so you could copy the keys instead and get the same behaviour by doing this -

```
a = {'p':'q','q':'r','s':'t'}

for key in list(a):
    if key == 'q':
        <some code here>
       del a[key]
       <some code here>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't change the size of a dict while you are iterating on it.

I suggest to create a copy of dict, delete element from the copy and then make the right assignement.

Make sure to do the copy with dict.copy() otherwise the code don't work to

```
a = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 }
b = a.copy()
for key in a:
  if i=='a':
    del [key]
a = b
```

Enjoy!